# Android Activity Stack Strange Behaviour

Tags: android, mobile, galaxy

My app normally works just fine, until I face a strange problem on specific device. When I start a new Activity for example:

> ActivityA.java
>
> Intent basvurularIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityB.class);
> startActivity(basvurularIntent);

After finish that activity

> ActivityB.java
>
> finish();

AcitivityB's onCreate() method triggered again. That's why ActivityB reloads its content. I encountered this issue 15 phones over 1.000 download of app. Example: Galaxy S3 Android OS 4.1.2. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Where do you call `startActivity` in your activity A ?

Comment: post relevant code of both activity A and B ...

Comment: @nicopico I call startActivity() inside of button click listener.

Comment: I have found a solution of this issue, please follow the link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36640559/3819836