# Android app crashes when calling any explicit intent (like camera/gallery, call or share) on Samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, explicit

I have compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion 23 and testing on Samsung galaxy s3. But whenever i open any third party app (explicit intent) like camera/gallery app or share intent (gmail, email) or dialer app and comeback to my app by pressing back button or (in case of camera/gallery app by selecting picture). App restarts from MainAcitivty (maybe it is getting crashed but it does not show any exception in logcat). Here is how i open intents:

Call/Dial:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Share:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, dialogHeaderText));
```

This issue is only coming in Samsung s3. I have tested all above functionalities on Google nexus 5, Huawei Honor 4C and Samsung galaxy s5 it is working fine. Any help?

Comment: Did you implement new permissions for Android 6 (sdk 23)? Did you also check to make sure the device is able to handle the intent?

Comment: Which sdk is running the galaxy s3?? and also can you provide the error stack from the log

Comment: @zgc7009 I think there is no need to add new permissions when calling intent. If it is issue of new permissions it should not be working on Nexus 5 (marshmallow 6.0) but it works fine on it. Havent got your second point how to check if device is able to handle intent?

Comment: @RafaelLucena galaxy s3 is running kitkat 4.4 and there is no error stack or any exception it just starts the MainActivity

Answer (score 4):

Every mentioned intent should have a callback mechanism, it is really strange in **Samsung S3**'s case where I have to face it. I have searched a lot but didn't find anything.

Somehow, I have seen an option in **Developer Options** titled as **Do not keet activities** which destroys every activity of user as soon as possible when checked. Please make sure that it is unchecked.

I have fixed it for Samsung S3 with Android version 4.3 and found that this option in many devices and Android OS versions

Please follow these steps:

Android version 4.3 (Samsung galaxy S3):

1. Go to **Settings** >> **More** (Tab) >> **Developer Options** >>
   **Do not keep activities**
2. Make sure this option is **unchecked**

General:

1. Go to **Settings** >> **Developer Options** >> **Do not keep
   activities**
2. Make sure this option is **unchecked**

Hope it will work :)

Comment: You have to turn this on to begin with, so be careful what you are doing as a dev with your devices. In fact, I believe that dev options are even hidden by default.

Comment: Yes for normal user this option is hidden by default, only developers can face this issue when enabled manually, otherwise it is unchecked by default for developer options.